# imagettfbbox() get boundaries and incorporate letter spacing

Tags: php

I use imagettfbbox() to calculate the dimensions of a bounding box.

For example:

```
$box = imagettfbbox(72, 0, 'My Font', 'My Message');
$width = (abs($box[2] - $box[0])) / 72;
$height = (abs($box[5] - $box[3])) / 72;
```

Is there anyway that I can incorporate letter-spacing into my message and retrieve the dimensions to the bounding box?

The letter-spacing would be in points, correct?

Thanks in advance.

Mike

Comment: what do you mean letter spacing? The [kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning)?

Comment: I'm referring to the CSS letter-spacing property.  If I had text with a height of 72 points and a letter-spacing of 10 points, could I incorporate that somehow into my bounding box calculation?  Is it possible?  Accurate?